# How to display character values for numerical data for many columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is a construction question. 
Usually when you have data in an statistic program format (R, SPSS) you have a label for each value (called a value-label). 
Let us say we have tree questions that are answered by three persons

```
         Q1|Q2|Q3
Person1||2 |1 |1 
Person2||3 |1 |2 
Person3||3 |2 |3
```

Each of these value has a value-label

```
1 = good
2 = neutral
3 = bad
```

My goal is to put these data into an sql server. But I am not sure how to accomplish that. My idea was to make two tables

First Table holds the answers per person for each question. Here each person gets an ID and the questions are the fields. Now I make a second putting the value and the valuelabel in. BUT with this construction I do not know how to query a table where all values are substituted by the valuelabels. I guess I'd have make a query like

```
Select * from Questions
left join labels
on questions.Q1 = labels.Labs
```

But for e.g. 1000 questions I would have to add the last line for each question? Could anyone help me who to construct the table, I do not want to make a construction mistake.

A result according to the example above 'd look like:

```
         Q1      |Q2      |Q3
Person1||neutral |good    |good 
Person2||bad     |good    |neutral 
Person3||bad     |neutral |bad
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on where the data is coming from? From what I can surmise, you already have these numeric identifiers and labels (good, not that good, etc) in separate tables, but you want to construct a table that holds both?

Comment: I will edit my question to make it more clear and answer your question.

Comment: Each question would need it's own set of labels. So a table for people, questions-header, questions-codeframe-for-answers and one link table for the results. In my experience you're better off not trying to normalise market research data if that's what it is. We normally have one table for each survey and another table for the lables for the survey.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But isn't that what I have? One table for the survey (that would be the first of my tables) and a second table for the labels of the survey (that would be my second table). If that is the normal way I am apparentely on the right path. But how do you query the tables to get the result (see above) I am looking for?

Comment: @ruedi No, your structure is different (and not that good). csmu hinted to results table, which has few link fields only - FK links to question, person and answer. Instead of you current Q1/Q2/Q3 fields it will include three records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * 
from Questions
left join labels as l1
on questions.Q1 = l1.Labs
left join labels as l2
on questions.Q2 = l2.Labs
left join labels as l3
on questions.Q3 = l3.Labs
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to avoid that, imagine I have 1000 questions, that would end up in a huge query. but big thanks for your help!

Comment: It all starts with your data design of questions.Q1.  1000 question is a 1000 columns.  I am just answering the question as stated.

Answer (score 0):

If 1, 2, and 3, are always good, neutral, and bad, you can store them in a kind of key/value pair table

```
    CREATE TABLE AnswerCodes(
        [AnswerValue] INT NOT NULL,
        [AnswerCode] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL --can make the column wider to store bigger values
    )

    SELECT Q.AnswerValue, AC.AnswerCode
    FROM [Questions] Q
    JOIN [AnswerCodes] AC
        ON Q.[AnswerValue] = AC.[AnswerValue]
```

Now, that will give you good results when pulling for just one column.  If you truly need to apply your labels to multiple columns of answer values, you can either

- Join to [AnswerCodes] for all of your value columns, or
- Use a pivot table to turn the results for each person into a row, with questions as the column.